# How partition a stateless Service Fabric service

Tags: c#, microservices, azure-service-fabric, partitioning, stateless

I would like to partition a **stateless** Service Fabric service. I didn't find how can I do that. 
I want to set the number to 10 for example.

*ApplicationManifest.xml*

```
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="MyService_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
    <Parameter Name="MyService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="10" />
  </Parameters>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by partitioning a stateless service? Stateless service instances are identical with each other (as they don't have state), therefore, partitioning for stateless services doesn't seem to have any benefit (and that's why it's not possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ApplicationManifest.xml*

```
<Parameters>
    ...
    <Parameter Name="MyService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="10" />
</Parameters>
...
<Service Name="MyService" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
    <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" InstanceCount="[MyService_InstanceCount]">
        <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[MyService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="0" HighKey="9" />
    </StatelessService>
</Service>
```